# TypeError nil can't be coerced into Float

Tags: ruby

I have a function that inserts values into an existing array
but this error keeps showing up

```
def apply_ks(s, n)
  frequency = s.length
   for t in 0..n
    s.insert(0.966*(s[t] + s[t+1])/2)
   end
   return s
end
```

The error states that

'+':nil can't be coerced into Float(TypeError)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming s is an array ...

Since you are accessing t+1 and t goes all the way to n, you should ensure that n < frequency - 1, otherwise you are accessing an element that is not in the array. Also, make sure that there are no nil values in s